Java Spring Boot: Test for utility class not run
I am very sorry if this question has already been asked but I could not find any answer for it.
In my Spring Boot application, I have a utility class that I use on several places in different services. The util - located in src/main/java/com/blueprint/bookings/util/AccountUtil.java - looks like this:
package com.blueprint.bookings.util;

... IMPORTS ...

public final class AccountUtil {
    private AccountUtil() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated");
    }

    public static Account getAccountFromRequestDto(RequestDto requestData) {
        ... CODE ...
    }

    public static UserEntity getUserEntityFromAccount(Account account) {
        ... CODE ...
    }
}

As I stated earlier I, this utility class and it's methods is used in several @Service classes, that is why I have created an utility for it.
Note that the utility class does not have any annotations. I tried annotating using both @Component and @Service but that just made all other (currently only controller) tests fail.
I want to write unit tests for this class and the methods. This is what I have done so far - located in src/test/java/com/blueprint/bookings/util/AccountUtilTest.java:
package com.blueprint.bookings.util;

... LOCAL IMPORTS ...
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AccountUtilTest {

    @Test
    void testGetAccountFromRequestDto() throws Exception {
        ... CREATE TEST OBJECT "testRequestDto" ...

        Account resultAccount = AccountUtil.getAccountFromRequestDto(testRequestDto);

        ... ASSERTIONS WITH "assertEquals" ...
    }

    @Test
    void testGetUserEntityFromAccount() throws Exception {
        ... CREATE TEST OBJECT "testAccount" ...

        UserEntity resultAccount = AccountUtil.getUserEntityFromAccount(testAccount);

        ... ASSERTIONS WITH "assertEquals" ...
    }
}


My problem here is that when I run mvn test or mvn install it does not get run at all. I see that other tests for my controllers and services are run but not this test.
I tried removing all tests but these, and then I see in the console, also indicating that these tests does not get run.
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

What might I be missing here?

I assume that you are not using Junit4 for testing these days, right? So if you are using Junit5, then you have imported wrong import org.junit.Test instead of import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test annotation. That could by why your test is not run. Nasty one...

Ooooh right. Now I feel more stupid than usual...

As AccountUtil is a utility class with static methods, it doesn’t need the Spring context to be loaded. Instead, it seems like a simple JUnit test class.
Here is the sample code snippet shown below through JUnit 5
class AccountUtilTest {

    @Test
    void testGetAccountFromRequestDto() {
        ... CREATE TEST OBJECT "testRequestDto" ...

        Account resultAccount = AccountUtil.getAccountFromRequestDto(testRequestDto);

        ... ASSERTIONS WITH "assertEquals" ...
    }

}

